# angular filter nested property clear

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to apply a filter on a sub element of my JSON object.

It works well but when i clear my filter, the properties without my sub element are not displayed.

Can you help me to do this ?

I can't modify the JSON structure
the JS code :

```
'use strict';
angular.module('filterExample', [])
    .controller('filterController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.amis =
        [{nom:'John', tel:'01-23-45-67-89', age:10, test:{id:3}},
         {nom:'Mary', tel:'02-34-56-78-91', age:19},
         {nom:'Mike', tel:'03-45-67-89-12', age:21, test:{id:5}},
         {nom:'Adam', tel:'04-56-78-91-23', age:35},
         {nom:'Julie', tel:'05-67-89-12-34', age:29, test:{id:7}}];
    }]);
```

HTLM code :

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Exemple 2 du filtre filter</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="filterExample">
    <div ng-controller="filterController">
      <h4>Objet pour le prédicat</h4>
      <p>
        N'importe quel champ <i>(search.$)</i> : <input ng-model="search.$"> <br/>
        Seulement à partir du nom <i>(search.nom)</i> : <input ng-model="search.nom"><br/>
        Seulement à partir de l'âge <i>(search.age)</i> : <input ng-model="search.age"> <br/>
        Seulement à partir du téléphone <i>(search.tel)</i> : <input ng-model="search.tel"><br/>
        Seulement à partir test <i>(search.test.id)</i> : <input ng-model="search.test.id"><br/>
      </p>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Âge</th>
            <th>Téléphone</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="ami in amis | filter:search">
            <td>{{ami.nom}}</td>
            <td>{{ami.age}}</td>
            <td>{{ami.tel}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

here is an example :
https://plnkr.co/edit/7RlfmKU2UkM13z0ogwmh?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing that is that once you 'clear' the id filter, the value of the id is still an empty string, and so the filter is still trying to match the `test.id` property, and therefore only looks at records with that property. In order to really clear it, you need to set the unset the `.test` property. You can do it by adding a watch for the id filter and unset when it is an empty string:

```
$scope.$watch('search.test.id', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== undefined && newVal.length === 0) {
        $scope.search.test = undefined;
    }
});
```